# Cycle through all history occurrences by typing first word and pressing up arrow without Oh-My-Zsh

Tags: plugins, zsh, history, oh-my-zsh, command-history

Is there a way to use OMZ's most loved feature to cycle through all history occurrences by typing first word and pressing up arrow without Oh-My-Zsh itself? I mean there should be some plugin for pure zsh for this, isn't it?

Like on this GIF

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic for that behavior lives over in https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/lib/key-bindings.zsh

It works just fine on its own outside of omz

Copy, paste, attribute :)